# Please help me understand this grammar: ようになるだけではなくて

Tags: grammar

I'm having trouble understanding this grammar. Could someone please help?

> 「ようになるだけではなくて」

Taken from the sentence:

> 本を読めるようになるだけではなくて

Comment: Your example "本を読めるようになるだけではなくて" does not look like a complete sentence.  It looks like only part of a sentence unless it is colloquialism.  If it is part of a sentence, please consider adding a complete sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking this apart a bit:

- [potential form+`ようになる`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B/UTF-8/) means "become able to..."
- `XだけではなくてY` means "not only X, Y"

So, (assuming there is something after `だけではなくて` and it's not a complete sentence), from there I think you can come up with:

> 本を読めるようになるだけではなくて…
>   Not only will (you) become able to read [a book/books], ...

---

The way I understand [`よう`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/0/0ss/120056100000/) is it means "state"/"situation"/"form"/"way", and is usually written in Hiragana though can be written with the Kanji `様{よう}`. So for example:

- `～ようになる` can mean "become into the state of...":

  > NGOはさらに大きな影響力を持つようになるのか。<sup>[1](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=NGO%E3%81%AF%E3%81%95%E3%82%89%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E5%BD%B1%E9%9F%BF%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%92%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A4%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B%E3%80%82)</sup>
  >   Will NGOs gain greater influence?
  > (lit. "Will NGOs become into the state of having greater influence?")
- `～できるようになる` can mean "become into the state of being able to..." or "become able to..."/"come to be able to..." etc:

  > あなたはすぐにもっと上手にテニスができるようになるでしょう。<sup>[2](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B&from=jpn&to=eng)</sup>
  >   You will be able to play tennis better soon.
  >   (lit. "You will soon become into the state of being able to do tennis more skillfully")
- `～ように` (often at the end of a sentence etc) can mean "towards the state/situation of..." or "may you..." etc, this is used for hoping or wishing for something:

  > あなたに不幸が訪れますように！
  >   May misfortune befall you!
  >   (lit. "Towards the state/situation of misfortune befalling you!")
- `XようにY` can mean "to go towards a state/situation of X, Y" or "X in order to Y":

  > 時間におくれないように家を出た。<sup>[3](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/0/0ss/120056100000/)</sup>
  >   In order to not be late, (I/he/she etc) left the house.
  >   (lit. "To not go towards a state/situation of being late, (I/he/she etc) left the house")
- `XのようなY` can mean "Y that's of a similar state/form to X", "Y that's like X":

  > 人生とは自転車のようなものだ。倒れないようにするには走らなければならない。<sup>[4](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=%22%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%22&from=jpn&to=eng)</sup>
  >   Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance you must keep moving.
  >   (lit. "Life is a thing that's of a similar state/form to a bicycle. ...")
- `よう` as in `どのよう` "how"/"what way" etc can also mean "way"

There are probably some other usages too.

**Edit:** tried to expand on the different usages of `よう`.

Comment: Thank you for those flushed out answer. By breaking the sentence up I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to break it down:

本を読めるようになる = so that [I] was able to read [the book/books/a book]

AだけではなくてB = not just A(but also)B....

> => Not just so that I could read books (but also)...

BTW: Just in case this wording sounds awkward, you have asked about a phrase not a complete sentence. The exact wording in English will depend on the rest of the sentence and the full context not provided, eg:

- Is this a specific book or books in general (see comments below)?
- The inclusion of なる (as per comments) suggests the latter(?)
- I assumed the subject was I but it could be 2nd person/more general
- I have used "just" which felt natural but "only" is perhaps technically a more precise word

*Supplementary grammar note:*
ために　is often translated as "in order to", ように　is often translated as "so that". The main difference b/w the two is that ために　is generally used for actions that can be controlled by the subject, ように　is typically used for verbs in potl form, -ve form or stative verbs such as 分かる. Compare the following two sentences

> 日本語を勉強するために日本にきました。
>
> 日本語が上手になるように一緒懸命勉強しています。

Comment: I thought 'in order to be able to read the book' would be 本を読めるために and 本を読めるようになる would mean 'to acquire the ability to read the book'

Comment: @taylor: see my supplementary grammar note. Changed "in order to" to "so that" to avoid confusion.

Comment: Wouldn't "Not just so that I could read the book" be 本を読めるようにだけではなくて ? With the なる present, I prefer the other (for some reason deleted) answer's interpretation of: "Not only will (you) become able to read [a book/books], ..."

Comment: @Hyperworm The translation here was originally written as "Not just in order to (be able to) read the book". I think I maybe would have written it as "Not just to become able to read [a book/books]", but I thought that assuming that it was a (lone colloquial) sentence as written in the question rather than having something after `だけではなくて`, it was a better translation than mine.

Comment: I originally wrote a quick answer to what I saw as a quick question. But, these are all fair points - not least the importance of being open to the context, which was not given. The OP does not explain what it is they don't understand. (FWIW, I thought it was probably だけではなくて because use of だけ is quite wide but taylor picked up on ように) For completeness, I'll try to incorporate your comments to my answer. Thanks